# Laravel Database Connection denied

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try connect to remote Database and get an error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user". I think the only reason  why it happened is absence rights to the DB  of user.
My env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=80.241.222.228
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databaseName
DB_USERNAME=databaseUsername
DB_PASSWORD=mypass
```

My config/database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '80.241.222.228'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'databaseName',
        'username' => 'databaseUsername',
        'password' => 'mypass',
]
```

Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: If 80.241.222.228 is a remote IP, in other words not the same server as the one you are trying to connect from, you will need to set up MySQL to allow remote connections, and allow the user to connect remotely.  Have you done that?

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh I know you were trying to help, but port-scanning someone and then publishing the results are really not good ideas.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for the tip